# In android Uri.parse clears the '#' sign

Tags: android, android-intent

I am trying to do this CallIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:*010*"+CardNumber+"#"));,that's a code you enter with the phone keypad at the call phone section ,when you enter that code it sends you sms with information about how much credit you have,how much points do u have,etc... when I use the call intent to do that the, it calls the entered number and clears the # sign which I don't wanna it to happen because this is a code not a phone number to call.When I enter that code in the call phone section it says activating the ussd code then it says wait for a message which will be send to you with the information.

I hope you guys understands what I have typed as it's hard to explain a bit,please if you didn't understand me tell me and I will do my best to understand what I need.

Thank's guys for your help

Comment: Question not constructive, refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
Uri.parse("tel:010" + Uri.encode( CardNumber + "#"))
```

you can also use '%' sign before your CardNumber in Uri.Parse without '#'.